# Having trouble Setting cookie and inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, session, post, cookies

I'm practicing on building an ecommerce website and I'm having trouble with the setcookie() function.

This is my add_cart file:

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/onlineStore/system/init.php';

$product_id = sanitize($_POST['product_id']);

$size = sanitize($_POST['size']);

$available = sanitize($_POST['available']);

$quantity = sanitize($_POST['quantity']);

$item = array();

$item[] = array(

    'id' => $product_id,
    'size' => $size,
    'quantity' => $quantity,
    );

$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '{$product_id}'");

$product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

$_SESSION['success_flash'] = $product['title'].' was added to your cart.';


//CHECK TO SEE IF CART COOKIE EXISTS
if($cart_id != ''){

//adding code later

}
else{
    //ADD CART TO THE DATABASE AND SET COOKIE
    $items_json = json_encode($item);

    $cart_expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+30 days"));

    $db->query("INSERT INTO cart (itmes,expire_date) VALUES 

('{$items_json}','{$cart_expire}')");

    $cart_id = $db->insert_id;

    setcookie(CART_COOKIE,$cart_id,CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE,'/',$domain,false);

}
?>
```

And another file where I define the cookie as a constant:

```
<?php 
define('BASEURL',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/onlineStore/');

define('CART_COOKIE','edHjw3345LKJ1z');

define('CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE',time() + (86400 * 30));
?>
```

When I inspect the page using the browsers developer tools it looks like the cookie is set after the page reloads but the value shows 0, the path shows n/a, the domain shows n/a, and expire shows n/a and the data isn't inserted into the database. Anyone know what's wrong? Please help.

I also have the $cart_id set in an if statement in my init.php file like so:

```
$cart_id = '';
    //IF COOKIE EXISTS, SET COOKIE TO cart_id
    if(isset($_COOKIE[CART_COOKIE])){

        $cart_id = sanitize($_COOKIE[CART_COOKIE]);
    }
```

Comment: I would take a rash guess and say your INSERT query has an error in it. `itmes` is this a spelling error.

Comment: I also dont see anywhere where you might be connecting to your database

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: That `sanitize` function probably doesn't do a very good job of escaping, either. Anything that obscures what's happening in terms of escaping is bad. If you need to manually escape something it should be obvious you're doing it correctly, not something left to assumptions. Even the tiniest of mistakes can have [disastrous consequences](http://codecurmudgeon.com/wp/sql-injection-hall-of-shame/).

Comment: Thanks for responding! It's good to have an outside perspective, looks like I overlooked that typo, but I went ahead and fixed the typo and I'm still having the same problem. =\ @RiggsFolly

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind! @tadman

Comment: @tadman In other words, I will ignore that

Answer (score 0):

So I've solved this problem by clearing the old cookie that I've set before and now everything seems to be working. Thanks for the help.